# DEM Raster Data hosted on GeoServer 2.15 serving OSGEarth platform

Tags: geoserver, dem, vrt

I can locally host **DEM** data and successfully read this data within **OSGEarth** application.

Yet when I host same data on **GeoServer (2.15)**, the **terrain disintegrates / shows spikes** all over respective terrain.

Data is being driven as **VRT dataset**...

Any ideas?

**Update - Imagery 11 Nov 2021**
Left image shows a locally hosted GeoTiff driving terrain accurately.
Right Image shows same data, hosted via GeoServer (with an associated SLD applied)

Cannot figure how to reign in displacement so its accurate...
[image: Local vs GoeServer hosted]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide a colormap for the terrain? Otherwise, each GetMap will have to turn the elevation values into a grayscale, using the local min/max values to do so.

Comment: OK, no I did not - as I did not need to do that when hosting data 'locally' - I shall try your suggestion, thanks!